# Использование ssh в C#

Tags: c#

[ssh либа для c#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11966/sharpSsh-A-Secure-Shell-SSH-library-for-NET?msg=2307383#xx2307383xx) Делал с помощью этой библиотеки соединение по ssh. Проблема в том, что мне нужно узнать вывод когда программа выполняетssh.Write("ps aux | grep gs"); .Подскажите как именно вывод узнать

Answer (score 1):

Так ведь там же и примеры есть -
http://www.tamirgal.com/home/SourceView.aspx?Item=SharpSSH&File=SshExeTest.cs

Выполняем команду - string output = exec.RunCommand(command);             
получаем результат - Console.WriteLine(output);

Answer (score 1):

На en so предлагают  [winscp](http://winscp.net/)

Он доступен тут https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library и из nuget консили https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install#nuget.

Поддерживает SSH, SCP, SFTP.

Классы `Renci.SshNet.SshClient`, `Renci.SshNet.ScpClient` и `Renci.SshNet.SftpClient` соответственно.  Много событий свойств калбеков.

Пример с# SFTP на сайте https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library#csharp

Источник http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86458/how-do-i-upload-a-file-to-an-sftp-server-in-c-sharp-net

Comment: `Renci.SshNet` – это не WinSCP – это SSH.NET.